# How to calculate video file size for H.264

Tags: h.264

I need to estimate disk usage for a media project. In order to do that I need to calculate typical file sizes for different video duration and resolution.

Example: Given a video with the properties below what is the formula to get the resulting file size?

fps: 20,
resolution: 480p,
duration 5 mins,
Encoding: H.264